# UpdatePanel (ASP), I lose inserted objects when I insert new objects dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, panel, updatepanel

I'm trying to insert one object (Panel) after another inside an UpdatePanel type object (by means of a button), this with the aim of forming an array that looks horizontal visually when the user inserts it inside the UpdatePanel. The problem I have is that every time I insert a new object, it deletes the previous one, that is, I insert object 2 and it deletes 1, if I insert object 3 it deletes 2 and so on only inserting an object inside. The two Textboxes that I use are to control the positions and know how many objects I already have inside.

I am using UpdatePanel, precisely to avoid losing those objects that I insert since each object will have a specific action within the array.

**How can I avoid losing the objects already inserted?, any idea?**

This is the code I am using

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim PanelS As Panel

        Dim pos As Int32 = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim numPanel As Int32 = Val(TextBox2.Text)

        PanelS = New Panel
        PanelS.ID = "pnl" & (numPanel + 1)
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "500px")
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "110px")
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, pos.ToString & "px")
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "absolute")
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundImage, "~/Images/W1.jpg")
        UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(PanelS)
        TextBox1.Text += 110
        TextBox2.Text += 1


    End Sub
```

and in ASP this is what I use

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="INSERT MOD" Width="120px" />
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">0</asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">20</asp:TextBox>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Waiting for your kind comments... ***Thank you in advance.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that on postback your `UpdatePanel` is getting reset. This needs to be beefed up a bit to handle adding the first one, etc. You might need to use `Page_PreRender` instead of `Page_Load` for example. I would recommend reading up on the page lifecycle. As-is the last one is duplicated but it should get you on the right track.

Also it's C# as I'm not that familiar with VB. Principles are the same, though.

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var numPanel = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < numPanel; i++)
    {
        var PanelS = new Panel();
        PanelS.ID = "pnl" + (i + 1);
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "500px");
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "110px");
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, (i * 110).ToString() + "px");
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "absolute");
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundImage, "~/Images/W1.jpg");
        UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(PanelS);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pos = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    var numPanel = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text);

    var PanelS = new Panel();
    PanelS.ID = "pnl" + (numPanel + 1);
    PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "500px");
    PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "110px");
    PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, pos.ToString() + "px");
    PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "absolute");
    PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundImage, "~/Images/W1.jpg");
    UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(PanelS);

    TextBox1.Text = (pos + 110).ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = (numPanel + 1).ToString();
}
```

**EDIT:** Using `Page_PreRender` example, which behaves more the way described:

```cs
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var numPanel = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < numPanel; i++)
    {
        var PanelS = new Panel();
        PanelS.ID = "pnl" + (i + 1);
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "500px");
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "110px");
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, (i* 110).ToString() + "px");
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "absolute");
        PanelS.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundImage, "~/Images/W1.jpg");
        UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(PanelS);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pos = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    var numPanel = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text);

    TextBox1.Text = (pos + 110).ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = (numPanel + 1).ToString();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and your effort. No problem for the code in C#, it's ok. I have already tried the code and I have done some tests and a slight adaptation and I only have a question about this. Assuming that "n" panels have already been entered and if I add one more, the previous objects at the moment of entering the page_load event, would I do them again?, that is, if I made any changes to them, this is lost and it goes to the configuration that the page_load event has, right? that it's because of the postback event of the button, correct?

Comment: Anything that needs to be persisted between button clicks has to be re-added in `Page_Load` (in this case). Your best bet is probably to move the generation of the UI into `Page_PreRender` and all the button does is add some info to `ViewState`. `PreRender` happens after control events where `Page_Load` happens before: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)

Comment: thank you again for your great answer and your effort. I am very grateful for the time you have taken and simply your answer is very good and works, to that I add the documentation that you have provided me to be able to correctly understand what you are providing me. Thanks again for this, very good job.